# Перенос проекта на сервер

Tags: ftp

Работаем с напарником над большим проектом,и каждый день нужно перезаливать изменения.Как правильно это делать? каждый день перезаливать полностью весь проект не удобно,но и смотреть какие файлы были изменены и заливать каждый по отдельности тоже не особо приятно.Как лучше перезаливать проект чтобы он  в это время оставался работоспособным

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Установите GIT на сервер и устройте там репозиторий. Сделайте папку репозитория открытой для web сервера. Если не знаете что такое GIT и как с ним работать, то [вот](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)

Comment: Спасибо попробуем. Гит знаю,работаем с ним.

Comment: А как проверить если на сервере Гит установлен? К хостерам обратится и спросить?

Comment: Если у вас нет доступа к консоли, то никак. Нужен vps

Comment: Ну я просто еще не сталкивался с подобным решением.Поэтому что мне нужно уточнить у хостера? Установлен ли у них Гит на сервере? и попросить доступ?

Comment: Если у вас нет доступа к консоли (то есть, у вас на VPS), то с гитом работать вряд ли получится

Comment: Есть VPS за довольно хорошие цены. Рекомендую Rootwelt.de (не реклама).